# Alchemy API - TextGetCategory does not work for me

Tags: uima, alchemyapi

When I use the endpoint http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetCategory and open CAS Visual Debugger and provide text as holiday locations in france or an url (http://www.guardian.co.uk/travel/france+beach) that is related to beaches in france, it always shows the category as unknown and score as 0.4. SO I tried giving a variety of text like "italian restaurants" or " smart phones", it gives the same category and score.

I took Alchemy API code from SVN sandbox and Eclipse is my IDE. I have not changed any default values for this api except that I gave my private api key. Has anyone faced the same or similar problems with TextGetCategory?

Any kind of inputs would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide examples of the text you are using?  If the text is too short the results become less accurate or indefinite, and whereas "Apple Computers" returns a pretty high score, "italian restaurants" is too short to determine the category properly.  Try some tests with more substantial amounts of text.

Additionally if you are submitting URLs make sure you are using the http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/url/URLGetCategory endpoint along with the "url" query string or post value and your api key.  When I do this I get results for the url http://www.guardian.co.uk/travel/france+beach reflecting that it is in the "recreation" category, as would be expected.

Hopefully that helps, let me know if it isn't sufficient!

Comment: This might have been better as a comment, to gain more clarity through questioning, before submitting an answer.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps you're right, my fault.  I was hoping that I was providing an accurate answer but given that I had a couple potential misunderstandings perhaps I should have asked first